# Swift nodeAtPoint difficulty

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am building a game in which the player drags a piece around the gameboard.  I wish to know what are all of the nodes underneath that piece, and I am getting odd results.  Here is the touchesMoves func:

```
    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

        let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self.parent)

        self.position = location
        println("checker x: \(location.x)")
        println("node at point: \(self.nodeAtPoint(location))")
        println("nodes at point: \(self.nodesAtPoint(location))")

    }
```

The sprite moves around the board just fine, but what is reported as the nodeAtPoint is always the sprite being moved around (which kind of makes sense but is not useful. Any oddly, the nodesAtPoint is always reported as an empty array!  How is this possible?  What should I be doing differently?

Update: This continues to be a struggle.  I want to keep the touch methods in the node itself, and not the scene.  The most recent version of the touchesMoved is the following:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

    // Turn off the touched bool:
    touched = false

    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self.parent)
    let loc = touch.locationInView(scene.view)
    let loc2 = touch.locationInNode(scene)

    self.position = location
    println("checker: \(loc2.x), \(loc2.y)")
    println("node at point: \(self.nodeAtPoint(loc2).name)")
    println("nodes at point: \(self.nodesAtPoint(loc2))")

}
```

The nodesAtPoint array continues to be empty with one really odd exception.  When hovering near the center of the scene, I get this:

nodes at point: [ name:'(null)' accumulatedFrame:{{-30, -19.80000114440918}, {60, 39.600002288818359}}]

There is not shape node there that I am aware of! Why am I not detecting the nodes I pass over?

Comment: What is `self` in this context?

Comment: This touch method is on the node being moved. However, I am thinking to move all touch behavior to the scene node and see if it works better then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the answer to this.  Essentially I was trying to detect nodesAtPoint on self, which in this case was the node being moved around the screen. Once I changed that to self.scene, the nodesAtPoint array populated as expected. So, to be clear:

```
println("nodes at point: \(self.nodesAtPoint(loc2))")
```

Needed to be changed to this:

```
println("nodes at point: \(self.scene.nodesAtPoint(loc2))")
```

Answer (score 1):

If `self` is `SKScene`, try to change

```
let location = touch.locationInNode(self.parent)
```

to

```
let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
```

because `SKScene`'s parent is `nil`

Comment: In this case, self is not the scene, but today I am going to move the touch method to the scene and see if that improves the situation.